# Layout difference between Chrome and Firefox, relating to floats and display: table

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7p81bnto/2/

HTML:

`<body>
    <main>
        <div>
            <div style="
                        height: 50px;
                        width: 200px;
                        background-color: green;
                        float: right;
                        "></div>
            <div style="
                        height: 50px;
                        width: 100%;
                        background-color: yellow;
                        display: table;
                        padding-top: 50px;
                        "></div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>`

Viewing these in Firefox and Chrome gives different layouts.
Can anyone explain why that is the case. I suspect it is related to the display:table property, but I don't really understand why.

For annoying reasons, I can't remove the display:table, but I need to get the body of the lower div lined up below the floating div.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve this consistently across both browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `{clear: both}` also achieves a correct look, and I think is arguably a better solution (by which I mean, one that ends up with CSS that more accurately reflects my design desires.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

`float: right`

to both divs and achieve the same look in both browsers.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75ux730g/2/

Comment: Thanks, this sorted it all out. Massively hacky, but such is the world of cross-browser CSS :(